# How to generate code form .raml with raml2code

Tags: code-generation, raml

I am trying to generate a code from .raml file using raml2code (https://github.com/gextech/raml2code).

Unfortunately the description isn't very good and I can't figure out how to do that.

Can anyone show me any example?

Comment: Just tried raml2code for the first time: it took two commands, one to install and one to run. Both commands are documented on the page that you've linked. What further example do you need?

Comment: Sorry wrong link. Here's the correct one: https://github.com/gextech/raml2code

Comment: Ah OK, then it's a different story :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I added more documentation, and also I'm working in a example project:

https://github.com/atomsfat/raml2codeFullSpringExample

Hope this help you